# Cursor in weird position only when in firefox panel

Tags: html, firefox-addon, twitter-bootstrap-3, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a firefox addon, that displays a panel via a widget.

If I load the html file directly, there are no problems.

However when using the form via the panel, the cursor goes to a weird position just below the final text input field if I press the submit button. I can also, briefly, reach this position if I press tab three times.

This only appears to happen when the html is loaded via the firefox addon widget->panel.

Here is an image to show the out of place cursor:

[image]

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<head>
<body>
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="col-centered col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="header">
                    <img src="../img/logo.png" height="100px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h3>
                    <p class="welcome-message">
                        Sign in or 
                        <a target="_blank" href="someaddress" class="create-account-link" id="create-account-link" >create  an account</a>
                    </p>
                </h3>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="username-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="password-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a id="login-button-link" type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-success block" style="width:100%">Sign In</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't find the bug I filed, but it's a bug and the fix has been implemented for the next version of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and should be fixed in FF 30 or FF 31:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=980714